# Convert OpenCV Mat in Java to NumPy Array in Scala

Tags: scala, numpy, opencv

I have a sample codebase in Scala where I use OpenCV and ScalaPy for doing some image classification. Here is the codebit:

```
def loadImage(imagePath: String): Image = {
  // 0. Load the image and extract class label where a path to the image is assumed to be
  // /path/to/dataset/{class}/{image}.jpg
  val matrix: Mat = imread(imagePath)
  val label = imagePath.split("")

  // 1. Run the loaded image through the preprocessors, resulting in a feature vector
  //val preProcessedImagesWithLabels = Seq(new ImageResizePreProcessor(appCfg)).map(preProcessor => (preProcessor.preProcess(matrix), label))
  val preProcessedImagesWithLabels = Seq(new ImageResizePreProcessor(appCfg)).map(preProcessor => preProcessor.preProcess(matrix))
  np.asarray(preProcessedImagesWithLabels)
}
```

It fails however for the reason that it cannot find an implicit converter for NumPy:

```
[error] /home/joesan/Projects/Private/ml-projects/object-classifier/src/main/scala/com/bigelectrons/animalclassifier/ImageLoader.scala:10:34: not found: type NumPy
[error]   val np = py.module("numpy").as[NumPy]
```

What is to be expected in addition to the imports?

```
  "me.shadaj" %% "scalapy-numpy" % "0.1.0",
"me.shadaj" %% "scalapy-core" % "0.5.0",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with latest "dev" version of scalapy-numpy: `0.1.0+6-14ca0424`

So change the sbt build in:

```
libraryDependencies += "me.shadaj" %% "scalapy-numpy" % "0.1.0+6-14ca0424"
```

I try in ammonite this script:

```
import me.shadaj.scalapy.numpy.NumPy 
import me.shadaj.scalapy.py 

val np = py.module("numpy").as[NumPy]
```

An it seems to find the `NumPy` as expected

Comment: With that out of the way, I face another error now as documented here in this new post, but somehow related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69794545/compile-error-with-opencv-and-numpy-integration